# SSH Server with User Authentication in GoLang

Tags: linux, authentication, go, ssh, server

I have been trying to make a SSH Server with GoLang (with either Wish or SSH Libary) but I can't figure out how I can make the Authentication User-Based so it works with the normal Username Password prompt from Putty for example.

This is the Code I currently have:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/charmbracelet/wish"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

const (
    host = "localhost"
    port = 2222
)

func main() {
    s, err := wish.NewServer(
        wish.WithAddress(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)),
        wish.WithIdleTimeout(5*time.Second),
        wish.WithPasswordAuth(""),
    )
    done := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(done, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    log.Printf("Starting SSH server on %s:%d", host, port)
    go func() {
        if err = s.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }()

    <-done
    log.Println("Stopping SSH server")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    defer func() { cancel() }()
    if err := s.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: `github.com/charmbracelet/wish` don't suport it

Comment: but it you can do "wish.WithPasswordAuth()" I just dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use `WithPasswordAuth` to validate the user's password.

Replace this line, `wish.WithPasswordAuth(""),` with something like this...

```golang
wish.WithPasswordAuth(func(ctx ssh.Context, password string) bool {
  log.Printf("Password is: %s, Username is: %s", password, ctx.User() )
  if ctx.User() == "me" && password == "secret" {
    return true
  }
  return false
}),
```

Then log into your ssh server, `ssh me@localhost -p XXXX` and if you enter `secret` your program will continue, otherwise your connection will be closed.